# How do you disable slider arrows on a header image in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

[Website home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuAoR.jpg)

Hello. I am using the Flash sitebuilder theme in Wordpress and I am wondering what kind of CSS I would have to use to disable these slider arrows, as I only want one image to be displayed. [The website link is here](http://www.producemymix.com)

Some of the CSS I've tried is

```
.swiper-button-next {
visibility:        none;
}

.swiper-button-prev
{
visibility:        none;
}
```

But I'm not really sure what I'm doing. Thanks

Comment: `visibility:none` doesn't remove the arrows, it just makes them invisible. Try `display:none` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
   <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal">
```

just remove this line and end <\div> .... hope this is work.